# Python eval error

Tags: python

```
x=5
print(eval('x+1',{'__builtins__': None}))
```

Getting Error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Why am I getting above error?

Also, How to specify only a few built-in methods for eval() function? For example, allowing only `max` and `min` functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [builtins docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html)

> The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module [[builtins]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) or the value of this module's `__dict__` attribute

To fix your error:

```
>>> print(eval('x+1',{'__builtins__': {'x': x}}))
```

To specify a few built-in methods, provide it to `__builtins__`

```
>>> print(eval('min(1,2)',{'__builtins__': {'min': min}}))
```

However, limiting `__builtins__` is still not safe: see https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: `__builtins__` is usually a module.  There is no reason that it "should" be a dictionary.  It's the second argument passed to `eval` which should be a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I getting above error?

Python tries to look for the name `'x'` within the builtins you've provided, and fails like that:

```
>>> None['x']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

You would need to include `x` in scope too:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> eval('x+1', {'__builtins__': None, 'x': x})
6
```

> How to specify only a few built-in methods for `eval()` function?

You can not sandbox this way.  It's always possible to escape the sandbox, for example via an attribute access on literals.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions would be to get current globals end clear the builtins

```
x=5
dictionary = globals()
dictionary['__builtins__'] = None
print(eval('x+1',dictionary))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the same reason why you don't get defined 'x' if you do:

```
x=5
print(eval("x+1",{'__builtins__': __builtins__}))
```

you get: `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` because you override all your context.

but if you just do:

```
x=5
print(eval("x+1"))
```

will print '6' but will use ALL the builtins functions, probably you just wanna do:

```
x=5
print(eval("x+1",{'__builtins__': {'min': min, 'max': max, 'x': x}}))
```