# Why does eval try to subscript on __builtins__?

Tags: python

```
>>> eval('potato', {'__builtins__': None})
NameError: name 'potato' is not defined
```

Python 2.  Makes sense.

```
>>> eval('potato', {'__builtins__': None})
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Python 3. How/why does `eval` try to subscript `None`?  I expected the same `NameError` here, or perhaps an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'potato'`.

<sub>Encountered via [Python eval error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51659933/674039)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `eval(expression, globals=None, locals=None)` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

> If the globals dictionary is present and lacks ‘`__builtins__`’, the
>   current globals are copied into globals before expression is parsed.
>   This means that expression normally has full access to the standard
>   `__builtin__` module and restricted environments are propagated.

But you are setting `__builtins__` to `None` in the globals dictionary, so your code will evaluate to `None['potato']` which leads to:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

EDIT:

Python2.7 raises `NameError` if it doesn't find the variable in `__builtins__` - [source code](https://github.com/certik/python-2.7/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L2058). `NAME_ERROR_MSG` is defined as:

```
#define NAME_ERROR_MSG \
"name '%.200s' is not defined"
```

Python3 print different message - see [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L2189) - the `PyObject_GetItem` will not raise `KeyError` but `TypeError` so the string is formatted differently, in this case `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

In CPython, the name `__builtins__` can be bound to a module or a dictionary.  That is [documented under the execution model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#builtins-and-restricted-execution):

> The builtins namespace associated with the execution of a code block is actually found by looking up the name `__builtins__` in its global namespace; this should be a dictionary or a module (in the latter case the module’s dictionary is used).

Comment: @wim But you aren't assigning into `None`, Python needs firstly load the variable. But it cannot load it from None.

Comment: @wim I linked the source code for Python2.7 and Python3. It's clearly seen, that Python2 formats the string in all cases, but Python3 only when KeyError is thrown.